# Attaching non-azure VMs to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

In the context of Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), I would like to deploy some pods to a region not currently supported by Azure (in my case, Mexico). Is it possible to provision a non-Azure VM here in Mexico and attach it as a worker node to my AKS cluster?

Just to be clear, I want Azure to host the Kubernetes control plane.  I want to spin out some Azure VMs within various supported regions.  Then configure a non-Azure VM hosted in Mexico as a Kubernetes Node and attach it to the cluster.

(Soon there will be a Microsoft Azure Datacenter in Mexico and this problem will be moot.  In the mean time, was hoping to monkey wrench it.)

Comment: By non-Azure do you mean an "on-premises" VM? Or a cloud providers VM within a datacentre in Mexico? Does it need to be in Mexico for locational reasons or for legal reasons? My understanding is that you can attach on-premises compute to AKS but I can't find a reference right now. You do of course require network connectivity between the node and AKS

Comment: By non-Azure, I mean a cloud provider VM with a datacenter in Mexico (am looking at HostDime).  Am thinking for locational reasons (for some events in Mexico and want low latency)

Comment: I did some reading and can't find any evidence that a non azure VM (which is just compute) can be connected. You might find there is very little difference in latency if you create the node in South Central US Azure zone. You can always deploy some kind of edge solution in mexico to feed the Azure node data

Comment: You are probably right about South Central US being more than good enough.  I already put my infrastructure there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a node pool with VMs that are not managed by Azure with AKS. You'll need to run your own k8s cluster if you want to do something like this. The closest you can get to something managed in Azure like AKS is to build your own [Azure Arc enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/overview) Kubernetes Cluster, but you'll need some skills with tools like `Rancher`, `Kubespray`, `Kubeadm` or something else.